# View and Hide Image Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying images before upload using jquery, when i upload some new files i want to remove or hide the previous upload files here's my jquery code:

```
$(function() 
    {
        // Multiple images preview in browser
        var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) 
        {
            if (input.files) 
            {
                var filesAmount = input.files.length;
                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) 
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(event) 
                    {
                        $($.parseHTML('<img class="p-3" width="350px" height="250px">')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        $('#file_input').on('change', function() 
        {
            imagesPreview(this, 'div#viewUploadItems');
        });
    });
```

And my HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="file_input" class="deletable" multiple />
<div id="viewUploadItems"></div>
```

I try this code but this won't display any image.

```
$("#file_input").on("click",function()
{
    $('input.deletable').val('');
    $('#viewUploadItems').remove();
});
```

Comment: `$('#viewUploadItems').html('');`

Comment: `.remove()` removes the element from the DOM - so it won't be there anymore when you go to add to it.  Use `.html("")` or `.empty()` to clear the content rather than remove the container.

Comment: `$('#viewUploadItems').empty();`

Comment: You're calling both `click` and `change` event in same element. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MoshFeu your method works thanks

Comment: @IkramKhizer consider checking the file type before attempting to preview it, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980209/8526705

Comment: Dacre Denny's answer is good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to clear the div before display : `$(placeToInsertImagePreview).html("");`

```
$(function() 
    {
        // Multiple images preview in browser
        var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) 
        {
            if (input.files) 
            {
                $(placeToInsertImagePreview).html(""); 

                var filesAmount = input.files.length;
                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) 
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(event) 
                    {

                       $($.parseHTML('<img class="p-3" width="350px" height="250px">')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        $('#file_input').on('change', function() 
        {
            imagesPreview(this, 'div#viewUploadItems');
        });
    });
```

Comment: when i try this this code then it will display only 1 image rather then displaying multiple images

Comment: I think you tried my first code I made some edition here

Comment: Cool best of luck bro; Can you please set my answer as Accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could take the following approach, where in your `imagePreview()` function you:

- first call `empty()` on the preview selector to clear any prior image contents
- then proceed to read and display any selected images, by using the `FileReader` API as you currently are (see below for revised approach)

Also, consider checking the type of the `file` object, to ensure that it is an image before attempting to display it via the following:

```
if (file.type.match("image.*")) {
    /* file is image type, so attempt to preview it */
}
```

Bringing these ideas together, you could revise your code as follows:

```js
$(function() {

  function imagesPreview(input, targetSelector) {

    /* Empty the target area where previews are shown */
    $(targetSelector).empty();

    /* Iterate each file via forEach in own closure */
    Array.from(input.files).forEach(function(file) {

      /* If file is image type proceed to preview */
      if (file.type.match("image.*")) {
      
        /* Create filereader and set it up for reading */
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          
          /* Append a new image element, prepopulated with
          required attrbutes, and assigned with p-3 class */
          $(targetSelector).append($('<img>', {
            width: '350px',
            height: '250px',
            src : reader.result
          }).addClass('p-3'))
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    })
  }

  $('#file_input').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div#viewUploadItems');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="file_input" class="deletable" multiple />
<div id="viewUploadItems"></div>
```

Comment: @IkramKhizer you're welcome - it's a good idea to ensure the file is of the correct type (as shown above) to ensure that it can be presented as an image (for instance, what would happen if someone selected an mp3 file?)

Comment: i am using this method only for images but i will think of it also later,